# Kendo UI Gantt chart - make splitter fixed?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

I am looking for a way to make the vertical splitter between the grid data and the graph data not resizable. I know the Kendo Gantt Widget uses a Kendo Splitter widget, but when I try to disable the resizable option, it completely hoses the chart; the code I tried is below. The #gantt ID is where my gantt chart renders.

```js
$("#gantt").kendoSplitter({
 panes: [ { resizable: false }, { resizable: false } ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not great, but a solution could be to return false for dragstart/mousedown on the splitter bar and set the cursor to default and pointer events to none:

```
$("#gantt .k-resize-handle").hide();
$("#gantt .k-splitbar").on("dragstart mousedown", function(e){
    return false;
}).css("cursor", "default").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

### **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/emALo)**

Comment: FYI, works in Chrome and FF, not in IE11 (surprise!), however.

Comment: @deaddancer, just add .css("pointer-events", "none");  Here is an updated demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/emALo (I also updated the answer)